# One product, multiple sellers

Tags: commerce

In a multiseller Drupal Commerce Installation, where every Drupal user being a seller,  Some products can be the same from all users, for example a book from some publisher which can be sold by many sellers. Like in amazon, if one is searching for a book, it comes up and shows other sellers also of that particular book.

Is there a way in Drupal commerce to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Sure! I would recommend you:

1. Create a taxonomy called "global_sku" ... Amazon calls their psuedo sku "ASIN" ... which is just a number that ties all the "product displays" to one page.
2. Now ... on your product displays, you could create a taxonomy reference to global_sku's
3. And then add some Views that will bring in [related products](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/131856/related-products-in-blog-post/131914#131914) based on the taxonomy.

Comment: Thank you very much. Seems Great. New horizons opened. One thing, as in case of Multiple sellers, will the Web Admin be doing all this once users submit products? or they can be a way so that sellers when submits such a product, the global_sku term is automatically added, as I think sellers wont like their prices to be compared or products.

Comment: Yeah, you could automate the global_sku process based on something pre-existing that would help you connect the dots (perhaps a manufacturer number or something similar) ... on product creation I would check if a similar product exists, if it does, connect them together with an existing taxonomy term, if one doesn't exist, create one.

Comment: Also, using http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions would allow you to hide this reference field from "sellers" and only show it to "web admin" or whatever your roles would be.